# How to slice datetime range with another datetime range

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new in Pandas and I can not find way, how to get a date ranges via slice using another date range.
Example with slicing from documentation using integer works well:

```
In [47]: pd.date_range('04-25-2016 10:00', '04-25-2016 20:00', freq='min')[1:3]
Out[47]: DatetimeIndex(['2016-04-25 10:01:00', '2016-04-25 10:02:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='T')
```

But slicing using another `date_range` is not working:

```
In [71]: work_range = pd.date_range('04-25-2016 10:00', '04-25-2016 20:00', freq='min')
In [72]: break_range = pd.date_range('04-25-2016 11:00', '04-25-2016 13:30', freq='min')

In [73]: free_time = work_range[break_range]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-361d67af3291> in <module>()
----> 1 free_time = work_range[break_range]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tseries/base.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    173             attribs['freq'] = freq
    174 
--> 175             result = getitem(key)
    176             if result.ndim > 1:
    177                 return result

IndexError: index -803545088 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 601
```

Or I using `date_range` wrong way?
My full example:

```
import pandas as pd


work_range = pd.date_range('04-25-2016 10:00', '04-25-2016 20:00', freq='min')

break_ranges = list()
break_ranges.append(pd.date_range('04-25-2016 11:00', '04-25-2016 13:30', freq='min'))
break_ranges.append(pd.date_range('04-25-2016 15:00', '04-25-2016 15:30', freq='min'))
break_ranges.append(pd.date_range('04-25-2016 13:00', '04-25-2016 13:05', freq='min'))

free_ranges = list()
for range in break_ranges:
    # slicing work_range here and put it into `free_ranges` list
```

Comment: is that what you want : `work_range[work_range.isin(break_range)]`? but it'll work only if all parts (date, time, hour, minute, etc.) are matching

Comment: btw, I certainly hope `date_rage` was a typo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DataFrame is indexed using the DatetimeIndex:

```
work_range = pd.date_range('04-25-2016 10:00', '04-25-2016 20:00', freq='min')
break_range = pd.date_range('04-25-2016 11:00', '04-25-2016 13:30', freq='min')
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(len(work_range))}, index=work_range)

>>> len(work_range)
601

>>> len(break_range)
151

>>> df.shape
(601, 1)

# Use `.loc` to select specific range.
>>> df.loc[break_range].shape
(151, 1)
```

If your index was a column value:

```
df['idx'] = df.index
>>> df.loc[df.idx.isin(break_range)].shape
(151, 2)
```

To exclude date ranges from the result, just use the tilda (`~`) negation character:

```
>>> df.loc[~df.idx.isin(break_range)].shape
(450, 2)
```

And if you are just using the index itself.

```
>>> work_range[work_range.isin(break_range)].shape
(151,)

# To exclude dates:
>>> work_range[~work_range.isin(break_range)].shape
(450,)
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I wanted to delete `break_range` from `work_range` using list method `reverse()`. But tilde is worked fine there. So, I end up as `work_range[~work_range.isin(break_range)].shape`